# Macports: specify compiler flags from command line

Tags: macos, boost, clang, macports, point-cloud-library

How can I pass compiler flags for C++ such as optimisation level, debugging symbols etc to port command? I need to build a library and its dependencies with c++11 support, which is not on by default, and can't seem to figure out how to do this without modifying the port tree.

Comment: Please add more detail, for example: Which version of OS X are you running, which version of MacPorts do you have, which flags do you want to set? Those are relevant to the question due to the changes Apple has done to standard library support of C++11 in recent releases.